# Designing Schema to Perform Sort Operation on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

Am using Mongoose to design schemas. I have two collections named **Restaurants** and **Products**. I have been storing all restaurant details in Restaurant Collection. In the **Products** Collection, I have a field named **restaurantCode** which is presented as **_id** in **Restaurant** Collection and mapped both collections successfully. Now on the Front-End side am using Angular 5, I have given control to the Restuarant Owner to sort the products as their wish. In order to perform this operation, I have created a new field in **Products** collection named **sortIndex** and assigned values from 0 to up to the number of products available per restaurant.  Posting my dummy data below

Restaurant Details

```
 1)
_id : "ABC",
"Name" : "Eat Well Restaurant",
 2)
 _id : "DEF",
"Name" : "Eat ALL Restaurant",
```

Product Details

```
1)
"name": "Pizza",
"Price": 20,
"restaurantCode" : "ABC",
"sortIndex": 0
2)
"name": "Juice",
"Price": 30,
"restaurantCode" : "ABC",
"sortIndex": 1
3)
"name": "Fruit",
"Price": 20,
"restaurantCode" : "ABC",
"sortIndex": 2 
4)
"name": "Chicken Rice",
"Price": 20,
"restaurantCode" : "DEF",
"sortIndex": 0
5)
"name": "Chicken Fry",
"Price": 20,
"restaurantCode" : "DEF",
"sortIndex": 1
6)
"name": "Chicken Briyani",
"Price": 20,
"restaurantCode" : "DEF",
"sortIndex": 2
```

Am displaying the products based on sortIndex value. Now, whenever a user performs sort Operation on front end side(Angular) i will re-assign the sortIndex value. The problem is whenever Restaurant Owner deletes a product i have to re-assign the sortIndex value for all the products associated with the particular restaurant. I feel it is a costly operation. This is the approach i have been using till now and it works fine. I wanted to know is there any better approach to this problem am sure there will be one. My stack is NodeJS,Mongoose,MongoDB,Angular(Front-End) Leave your ideas/thoughts. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems your design is something like

```
var restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    Name: String
});

var productSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    Price: Number,
    restaurantCode: { type: String, ref: 'Restaurant' },
    sortIndex: Number
});

var Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

If you want to keep both collections, you could instead add a field `products` to your Restaurant schema and do-away with `sortIndex` in your Product schema. This `products` field would be a sorted array of references (not sorted by their IDs but by their positions).

```
var restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    Name: String,
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }] 
});

var productSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    Price: Number,
    restaurantCode: { type: String, ref: 'Restaurant' }
});
```

When you save the sort order of a list of products for a particular restaurant, you would have to send an array of all the product IDs in the order that they are placed.

When you delete a product, you would delete it from the Products collection and remove the reference in the related restaurant. Usually, if you follow RESTful design, your delete route would be like `DELETE /restaurants/:rid/products/:pid`.

Comment: Mikey i don't think this will be a good apporach as i have many fields in restaurant schema as well as in products schema i just posted the required fields. Can you give me/think of an any other idea?

Comment: @Kannan Why do you think it is a bad approach? This approach simply maintains the order of the `products` reference array in **one** Restaurant document -- with the added benefit in terms of fetching related [products](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Though, it's hard to answer as I don't know how you designed your UI particularly for sorting. Do you sort + save **one** product at a time OR sort + save **all** products at a time? Are you also **only** sorting OR sorting + updating other fields for each product?

Comment: Bro am not saying this is a bad approach at all what am saying is this is not a good approach for my problem. I already have 1000 restaurants and each one has at least 100 products so going to separate collection was a good idea for me. And a product has 25 fields itself and it will be very hard to store into a single collection.

Comment: Am performing sort via a field value(sortIndex) an user drag and drop the product i will get both the sortIndex value and i will change the sortIndex of those products.